# Adding 1 to a number and replacing the original number

Tags: c#

At the minute my code adds 1 to 100 every 3 seconds. It's displayed 10102103104105. What i want is the 101 to disappear and the 102 to be there instead and so on

```
int i = 100;

private void timer5_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    textBox2.Text += i.ToString();    
}
```

Comment: Change the line to `textBox2.Text = i.ToString();`

Comment: `+=` is a concatenation operation.  You can simply assign the value of `i` instead, no?

Comment: Don't add strings, that is concatenation.  Add numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

```
textbox2.Text += i.ToString();
```

This is a shorthand way of writing this:

```
textbox2.Text = textbox2.Text + i.ToString();
```

So if your textbox contains `100` already, what you are saying is this:

```
textbox2.Text = "100" + i.ToString();  // The textbox now contains "100101"
```

On the next iteration, it looks like this:

```
textbox2.Text = "100101" + i.ToString();  // the textbox now contains "100101102"
```

And so forth....So change the line to this:

```
textbox2.Text = i.ToString();
```

So if your textbox contains `100`, this is what happens on the next iteration:

```
textbox2.Text = i.ToString();  // the textbox now contains "101"
```

And so forth...

The `=` operator means `Assign the value on the right hand side of the equal sign to the variable on the left hand side`.

The `+=` operator means `Append the value on the right hand side of the equal sign to the contents of the variable on the left hand side`.

See the difference there? `Assign` vs. `Append`

Answer (score 3):

You're appending the value of `i` in your method. You need to just assign the value.

```
int i = 100;

private void timer5_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    i++;
    textBox2.Text = i.ToString(); // ASSIGN HERE!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the value to the text box, not append it.

```
textBox2.Text = i.ToString();
```